# Password encryption causing membership form field to test as having value even when empty

Tags: php, forms, md5, membership

I am implementing a membership registration form in PHP.

The password variable is encrypted with md5. This appears to be preventing the test that checks for empty form fields from correctly identifying that the password field is empty.

So the form is being submitted even when no password is present and an encrypted value is being placed in the MySQL database.

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the form fields *before* applying md5()

Answer (score 0):

Check before encryption

```
$pass = trim($_POST['password_field']);
if(empty($pass))
{ 
//stop process
}
else
{
$encrypt = md5($pass);
//store in DB
}
```